# MarketStack End of Day API results stop at May 3 for London Stock Exchange

Tags: rest, stock, stockquotes

The MarketStack eod API returns end-of-day data for stocks.  This has been working fine, but recently I've found that data for stocks in the London Stock Exchange (XLON) only goes up to the 3rd of May 2023.  This is my API call (with the access key removed)

http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=XXXXXXXXXXX&symbols=TSCO.XLON

Data from other stock exchanges goes up to yesterday's date.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because debugging a third-party API is not a good fit for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.  Try contacting the company's tech support channel instead.

Comment: I have the same problem for the Swedish Stock Exchange, XSTO.

Answer (score 0):

To get Historical Data you should define date_from and date_to.
In response you will see "pagination" and "data".

```
https://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=xxxxxx&symbols=your_symbol&date_from=date_in_format_YYYY-MM-DD&date_to=date_in_format_YYYY-MM-DD&limit=1000
```